# label table rows and columns in matlab?

Tags: matlab, label, matlab-table

I am trying to make row and variable names in matlab like this:

```
labeledtable = table(NaN(4),'RowNames',cellstr(('a':'d')'),'VariableNames',cellstr('e':'h'));
```

The row names look good, but I want e f g and h to correspond to the four columns of the table, as opposed to 'efgh' just being one variable name for all four columns. How do I label each column separately?

```
 %------------
```

Here's what I was looking for:

```
labeledtable = array2table(NaN(4));
labeledtable.Properties.RowNames = cellstr(('a':'d')');
labeledtable.Properties.VariableNames = cellstr(('e':'h')');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

- Transposing like you did for the RowNames: `cellstr(('e':'h')')'`
- Use [num2cell](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html): `num2cell('e':'h')`

I'm not sure which of these performs better in terms of speed, but it doesn't look to be a large concern for you. I would recommend the second due to readability.

Comment: I think my real problem is that if I say labeledtable = table(nan(4)) that creates a 4x1 table where each row is 1x4, when I really want a 4x4 table.